# How did 'circumscribe' evolve to mean 'Restrict (something) within limits'?

Tags: etymology

What's an intuitive derivation behind [ODO's definition 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/circumscribe) that helps to remember its meaning:

> 1. **circumscribe** = Restrict (something) within limits:
>
> [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=circumscribe&searchmode=none): late 14c., from Latin circumscribere "to make a circle around, encircle, draw a line around; limit, restrain, confine, set the boundaries of," from **circum-** "around" (see circum-) **+ scribere** "write" (see script (n.)). Related: Circumscribed; circumscribing.

Yet how does the idea of 'writing around' something restrict that something?

Comment: Defining ('writing') the limits (boundaries, 'circle'-of-freedom/ operation/ existence/ influence/ control) HTH. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakshmana_rekha

Comment: A good proportion of these -scribe words have extended (from the purely graphic sense) senses: _prescribe_, _proscribe_, _subscribe_, and in a usually more limited way, _describe_. 'Scribe' is the root morpheme here, not a suffix.

Comment: Writing does not only mean "put a pen on paper and form letters". Any but the _most restricted_ interpretation of writing would make the meaning of circumscribe immediately clear. Try to be flexible when reading something into meaning, _especially_ in etymology: _draw a line around something_ quite obviously can be read as _set boundaries around something_.